# Как импортировать npm-модули при помощи require.js?

Tags: javascript, npm, babel

Привет. Как правильно импортировать модули npm в браузер? Использую npm с Babel, где после установки модуля я прописал `import 'webpack';`, что в транспилированном коде равняется `require('webpack');`. Я подключил к странице транспилированный `index.js` и получил ошибку `requeire is not defined`. Долго пытался понять, как же мне импортировать модули и наткнулся на [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined), где сказано, что лучше всего использовать для таких целей WebPack. Что ж, так и сделал - ввёл `npm i webpack --save`, но погоды это не сделало. Попытался подключить на странице requeirejs через `<script>`, но получил гору ошибок в консоли и `Module name "webpack" has not been loaded yet for context`. Что я делаю не так и правильно ли я делаю вообще, что пытаюсь подключить к странице транспилированный код?

Comment: просто подключить webpack в проект не достаточно. необходимо настроить его.

Answer (score -1):

Синтаксис import:

```
import {one, two} from "./nums";
```

Здесь:

`./nums>` – модуль, как правило это путь к файлу модуля.
one, two – импортируемые переменные, которые должны быть обозначены в nums словом export.
В результате импорта появятся локальные переменные one, two, которые будут содержать значения соответствующих экспортов.

Например, при таком файле nums.js:

```
export let one = 1;
export let two = 2;
```

Модуль ниже выведет «1 and 2»:

```
import {one, two} from "./nums";

alert( `${one} and ${two}` ); // 1 and 2
```

Импортировать можно и под другим именем, указав его в «as»:

```
// импорт one под именем item1, а two – под именем item2

import {one as item1, two as item2} from "./nums";

alert( `${item1} and ${item2}` ); // 1 and 2
```

Импорт всех значений в виде объекта
Можно импортировать все значения сразу в виде объекта вызовом `import * as obj`, например:

```
import * as numbers from "./nums";

// теперь экспортированные переменные - свойства numbers
alert( `${numbers.one} and ${numbers.two}` ); // 1 and 2
```